# How i can call method without button click in odoo?

Tags: python-2.7

I have created demo module in `odooV10`, in which I created simple method to
print the value in console, I have created following method to print value

```
@api.multi
def test(self):
a=5
b=10
c=a+b
print c
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use Scheduler

   ** So you can create scheduler.**
2. Create in function

`Create function in scheduler function`